# Выполнение программы и мнгновенное завершение

Tags: python, консоль

пишу не первый раз бота в дискорде, но с таким столкнулся впервые. Скрипт как бы выполняется, но в то же время и нет. Снизу будет вывод из консоли

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot( command_prefix = ".")

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("Я подключился!")

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f"Hello, {author.mention}")
 
client.run =
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хотя если пробовать на простых примерах по типу ```print("123")``` все работает хорошо

Comment: Во первых, скрипт неполный, а во вторых, в приведенном скрипте нечему выполняться

Comment: да, но ведь он должен войти в сеть в дискорде. про неполный скрипт не понял. токен я не стал вставлять, так что тут все нормально. так же ведь прописано, что при включении он выведет в консоль "Я подключился!"

Comment: Скрипт заканчивается client.run = Так скрипт заканчиваться не может, значит, в нем не хватает продолжения

Comment: так, то есть если правильно закончу конец, то все запустится?

Comment: Ну если правильно, то да. Но вообще, то, что написано сейчас, должно выдавать ошибку. Точно в вопрос весь код скопирован?

Comment: да, скопирован полностью весь код

Comment: почему должно выдавать ошибку?

Comment: Потому что после знака = должно ещё что-нибудь быть

Comment: так я ведь говорю, что там токен находится

Comment: сейчас чутка изменю, скину

Comment: ага, не скину. лимит символов

Comment: в текст вопроса добавляйте, а не в коментарий. Там должен быть полный код (значение токена замените на что угодно, но чтоб синтаксически все осталось как у вас)

Comment: откуда у вас с коде присваивание - неясно. в примере https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html вызов функции

Comment: Если там написано "client.run = токен", то что должно быть в консоли? Значение присвоилось, скрипт завершился. Ни одной строчки для вывода чего бы то ни было в скрипте не было выполнено.

Answer (score 1):

я запустил твоего бота все воркает посмотри последнюю строчку мейби токен не так писал

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot( command_prefix = ".")

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("Я подключился!")

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f"Hello, {author.mention}")
 
client.run("ODU0MDgxMzM4N5.типо_токен.KeXni7h275GxLOaU")
```